# My 7 year old Son is out of control and has been expelled from school

Tags: behavior, primary-schooler

My 7yr old son Josh is out of control. I can't leave him alone with his brother, I cant go shopping with him, I cant drive with him in the car, he wont sleep, he cant go to school and I cant cope. Josh is always causing trouble in school he's had 3 warnings and has now been asked to leave. At school he swears at everyone he fights, he spits, within the last 2 years at school he has broken a girls arm by pushing her off the climbing frame, and a boys leg by hitting him with a hockey stick, last month Josh put a pillow over a little boys head until he was left gasping for air so was asked to leave.

When I go shopping with Josh he will knock everything off the shelves and swear at me from across the isles. In town he won't move and will lay on the floor and cry, if I don't give in to him he will take off his pants and pee in the middle off the streets. In the car he won't wear a seatbelt and will constantly undo his 4 year old brothers. I have tried naughty step,chair,room ignoring him and rewards nothing works. How do I stop his behaviour?, his worst habit is he will pee everywhere, in the car, in the bed, in the shops, at school its disgraceful. I was in john lewis buying clothes for a party and Josh wanted to leave I wouldn't let him so he took off his pants, went to the middle of the floor naked just with a top on and aimed his pee everywhere, I got kicked out the shop, then he wouldn't put his clothes on so i had to carry him out naked. I can't do this anymore I cant cope.

Comment: Your son needs professional help urgently. This is a long way south of acceptable, normal behavior. He's only a child now, but he will reach an age very soon where this kind of behavior will land him in juvenile detention, and later prison.

Comment: You need to be very careful, and ensure he's never left alone with younger children. He could well be a danger to your other children.

Comment: One thing that's particularly disturbing is that he has seriously injured 2 children, and almost killed a 3rd. He should not be allowed back into a normal school until he is getting appropriate treatment, and even then only with very strict supervision.

Comment: Though it's clear there's a big problem, there is no clear question here; please see the [site tour](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/tour), the [help sections](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help) (especially [Asking](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/asking)) for more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Your child needs professional help.

He's caused severe injury to two other children and nearly murdered a third.

Talk to your pediatrician immediately and get a referral for a psychiatric evaluation before he causes more harm.